# Python Streamlit running on Heroku - how to get remote/client ip?

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

I was able to deploy an Streamlit App to Heroku. I did that to compare Heroku and Streamlit Share. Both runs fine, but I want to log client's IP (remote IP) to understand where my app is getting accessed from.

I'm googling for two days now without success. I saw a lot of posts related to the subject, most discussing how to get the real IP, where is it `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` and so on.

At first I understood that `ENV['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` was a environment var which I could get and parse using `os.environ['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` but it is not the case. I even tried `request.headers['X-Forwarded-For']` which requires Flask but I learnt that Flask and Streamlit do not get along. Other solutions dealing with PHP/Java are beyond my knowledge.

So, my question is: **"Is it possible to get remote IP using a Python package, without Flask?"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the client inform the IP address to the host by using the `streamlit-javascript` package and inserting a JavaScript code that access an external service, e.g. [api.ipify.org](https://api.ipify.org).

```
import streamlit as st
from streamlit_javascript import st_javascript


def client_ip():

    url = 'https://api.ipify.org?format=json'

    script = (f'await fetch("{url}").then('
                'function(response) {'
                    'return response.json();'
                '})')

    try:
        result = st_javascript(script)

        if isinstance(result, dict) and 'ip' in result:
            return result['ip']

    except:
        pass


ip_address = client_ip()  # now you have it in the host...

st.write(ip_address)  # so you can log it, etc.
```

It's not a perfect solution (as it won't be of any use inside a NAT, for instance), but I think it's as far as you can go with Streamlit.

Of course, acquiring the request IP from Tornado (the webserver) could be a Streamlit feature, [but it isn't just yet](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/a-way-to-grab-the-request-ip-from-tornado/).

Comment: Although it's meant for internal use only, you can access a non-public part of the API to acquire the request IP from the webserver (in versions 1.8 and 1.9):
|
from streamlit.scriptrunner.script_run_context import get_script_run_ctx \
from streamlit.server.server import Server \
session_id = get_script_run_ctx().session_id \
session_info = Server.get_current()._get_session_info(session_id) \
request = session_info.ws.request \
headers = session_info.ws.request.headers  # the dict you want
|
Keep in mind that those functions and names can be changed in future Streamlit versions.